# MySQL full-text search using match against return wrong result set

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE is_active = 1 AND MATCH (full_text) AGAINST ('М 1050' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This query returns two records, here's the full_index column contents of both:

> ; 013 001 106 ; Ъглошлайф SPARKY **M 1050** HD ; 1050W,10000об.,ф125мм
>   ; SPARKY ; 69 ; ; 040 070 **1050** ; Вложка дванадесетограм удължена ;
>   1/4" 5мм FORSE /5295005/ ; FORCE ; 77 ;

But I want only the first row, I don't need the second one. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answer provided by user144590; `M` is not, by default, considered a word.

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

> Any word that is too short is ignored. The default minimum length of words that are found by full-text searches is three characters for InnoDB search indexes, or four characters for MyISAM. You can control the cutoff by setting a configuration option before creating the index: innodb_ft_min_token_size configuration option for InnoDB search indexes, or ft_min_word_len for MyISAM.

**UPDATE**

Without changing the minimum length I guess you'd have to replace (in the column data) the space in the text `'M 1050'` with another word character like `'_'` and match against `'M_1050'` (in the query), or run a much slower `LIKE '%M 1050%'` condition.

Comment: Maybe that's the key. When I am using `+`, the same result set is returned. Is there a way to ignore the `М` letter without changing the minimum length of words, because I don't have access to configuration file?

Comment: @KristianVitozev Isn't ignoring the `M` exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Well, it seems that `М` is ignored, that's why I have the both results. But I want only first result to be matched (where the letter `M` actually exists)

Comment: Thanks, but using `M_1050` we don't have any results. :/

Comment: @KristianVitozev Did you replace it in the actual column data as well?

Comment: If you wrap the query inside single quotes also in double quotes it searches on the whole phrase: ...`AGAINST( '"M 1050"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`...

Comment: @MatejSvajger, yes but it splits that phrase into words internally to perform the search and will still ignore 'M' as it is not a word. [See Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: @Arth I didn't know that! From what I could gather from docs; wrapping a string in double quotes would treat it as a single phrase, but there is no mention it splits it into words! That explains the headache why my search results were still off :/ Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @MatejSvajger No problem, it does mention it in the bullet labeled " a little way down the page I linked to. Also, the full text index indexes words, that's how it works quickly. If the phrase signifier " was a literal character match then the words indexed would be useless and the query would be no faster than `LIKE "%phrase%"`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

> Note
>   In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in  which
>
> plus(+) stands for AND
>
> minus(-) stands for NOT
>
> [no operator] implies OR

So essentially you are doing an OR, if you need both the terms use + as such

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE is_active = 1 AND MATCH (full_text) AGAINST ('+М +1050' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match some words exactly, use double quotations mark (e.g '"М 1050"')

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE is_active = 1 AND MATCH (full_text) AGAINST ('"М 1050"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```